# Whats the proper idiom for naming django model fields that are python reserved names?

Tags: python, django, idioms

I have a model that needs to have a field named `complex` and another one named `type`. Those are both python reserved names. According to PEP 8, I should name them `complex_` and `type_` respectively, but django won't allow me to have fields named with a trailing underscore. Whats the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no problem with those examples.  Just use `complex` and `type`.  You are only shadowing in a very limited scope (the class definition itself).  After that, you'll be accessing them using dot notation (`self.type`), so there's no ambiguity:

```
Python 2.6.2 (release26-maint, Apr 19 2009, 01:58:18) 
[GCC 4.3.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class Foo(object):
...     type = 'abc'
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.type
'abc'
>>> class Bar(object):
...     complex = 123+4j
... 
>>> bar = Bar()
>>> bar.complex
(123+4j)
>>>
```

Comment: Technically, the examples you gave are not reserved words.  They are builtins.  Reserved words (like print or lambda) will cause actual problems.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to use the `db_column="complex"` argument and call your field something else?